# Proper setup for Mecanim standing jump animation

Tags: unity, animation, jumping, mecanim

I have a character **standing jump** animation with that the character at start prepares for the jump (flexing downwards) and then jumps up in the air and i'm wondering how to get it working properly with Mecanim in Unity.

The difficulty is that the jumping in my code isn't just an on/off trigger but is triggered by a Y velocity that determines how high the character can jump.

With my current approach, when jumping the character lifts instantly off the ground and then executes the starting part of the animation which of course looks wrong.

Is there any way to configure single jump animations with Mecanim to work with a Y velocity or do I have to split the animation into three parts (prepare/jump/landing) for this?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about multiple things here: One is that you want a "warm up" animation before the main part of an animation (which represents changing world data) begins. Another is that you want the animation to progress according to the character's Y velocity. Am I right? Any way we could split this into 2 questions? The second one sounds a lot like a duplicate of [this other question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63737/jumping-with-mecanim-synchronization?rq=1).

Comment: The animation already has a warm-up part. It's one animation file with a complete jump in it. And I want to know if it can be used in a case where a jump velocity is used or if it's a no-go without splitting the animation into multiple parts. I.e. is there a way to tell Mecanim to wait with the jump velocity until that actual jump starts? Also: The velocity calculation is already done so that's not an issue.

Comment: Still no answer. I was wondering would it possible to control the mid-phase of the jump via animation events and looping?